# Writing a general print function for arrays in C

Tags: c, printing

I am new to C and I am trying to write a function called "print_array" that prints out any arrays of type int, float and double. I am trying to do this by function overloading (I read about this in a book). So I came up with the following code:

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

#define len(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

#define print_array(array, length_array)_Generic((array), double: print_double, float: print_float, default: print_int)(array, length_array)

void print_int(int *array, size_t length_array) {
    printf("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < length_array-1; i = i+1) {
        printf("%d, ", array[i]); }
     printf("%d} \n", array[length_array-1]); }


void print_float(float *array, size_t length_array){
    printf("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < length_array-1; i = i+1) {
        printf("%f, ", array[i]); }
    printf("%f} \n", array[length_array-1]); }


void print_double(double *array, size_t length_array) {
    printf("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < length_array-1; i = i+1) {
        printf("%f, ", array[i]); }
    printf("%f} \n", array[length_array-1]); }



int main()
{
    int A[3] = {1,2,3};
    double B[4] = {1.2, 3, 4.5, 6.8};
    float C[4] = {1.2, 3, 4.5, 6.8};
    print_int(A, len(A));
    print_double(B, len(B));
    print_float(C, len(C));
    printf("____________________________________________________ \n");
    print_array(A, len(A));
    print_array(B, len(B));
    print_array(C, len(C));
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that I defined a macro called "len" to get the length of arrays quickly. 
The functions "print_int", "print_float" and "print_double" are straightforward printing functions for the corresponding array type.

I tested these functions in the main function and they do as I expected. But my function "print_array" prints some weird values for the float and double type, but it works for the int type. 
Here is my output:

```html
{1, 2, 3}
{1.200000, 3.000000, 4.500000, 6.800000}
{1.200000, 3.000000, 4.500000, 6.800000}
____________________________________________________
{1, 2, 3}
{858993459, 1072902963, 0, 1074266112}
{1067030938, 1077936128, 1083179008, 1088002458}

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.031 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the *`default`* generic association for *every case* that compiles... If you'd put `int` case separately you'd notice that it is never selected.

The problem is that you're selecting by the *array type*, instead of the element type. Try

```
_Generic((*array), ...)
```

to actually use an *array element* as the controlling expression.

With this one-character fix the output is

```
{1, 2, 3} 
{1.200000, 3.000000, 4.500000, 6.800000} 
{1.200000, 3.000000, 4.500000, 6.800000} 
____________________________________________________ 
{1, 2, 3} 
{1.200000, 3.000000, 4.500000, 6.800000} 
{1.200000, 3.000000, 4.500000, 6.800000}
```

---

Actually you *should have gotten many warnings*, for example:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘print_int’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         print_array(B, len(B));

note: in definition of macro ‘print_array’
 #define print_array(array, length_array)_Generic((array), double: print_double, float: print_float, default: print_int)(array, length_array)
                                                                                                                         ^~~~~
111111.c:10:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘double *’
 void print_int(int *array, size_t length_array) {
      ^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this fixed it.